# SQL Replication not working correctly.

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication, transactional-replication

I have a transactional SQL Server replication set up. Currently everything I have review seems to show that the replication is working. I have reviewed the Replication Monitoring and Sync State and both show that transactions are being pushed across correctly.

The problem I am having is that some of the replicated tables aren't even coming across while other are. Is there a better way to look deeper into Replication to find out why things aren't coming across?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this `The problem I am having is that some of the replicated tables aren't even coming across`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the tables are selected as articles in the publication properties?  If so you may want to try validate subscriptions.  As a last and most manual resort you can use tablediff.exe to compare two tables.  The EXE will be located on your SQL server and will need to be run from the command line.  Here's the syntax that worked for me. Replace the all caps items with names for your environment.

`tablediff -sourceserver INSTANCE1 -sourcedatabase DATABASE1 -sourcetable TABLE1 -destinationserver INSTANCE2 -destinationdatabase DATABASE2 -destinationtable TABLE2`